# const variable: has already been declared

Tags: javascript

I've been looking for a solution for three hours now! 
am trying to create a form validation with Javascript.
here is may js code(not finished yet):

```
const username = document.getElementById('usernameblank');

function usernamevalide(){
      const usernamevalue = username.value.trim();

}
```

why am I getting this error in the console " Identifier 'username' has already been declared".

thanks

Comment: How/where do you run this code? Directly in the browser console?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Can you give a bit more context?

Comment: no. I use sublime text.     I want to get username input from a form in a page called signup.php then check if it is valid with javascript before storing it in the datebase with php.

Comment: you are probably declaring username somewhere else in the app.   I can't reproduce this either.   Are you sure it's not a linter error?    Please create a https://jsfiddle.net/ and post the link in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Const keyword creates block-scoped variables whose values can't be reassigned.

Answer (score 0):

> Identifier 'username' has already been declared

You must have already declared a variable named "username" in your code.

OR

If you running this code directly in your console then run it in a new browser console. Running it in the same console will show this error.

Comment: Identifier 'username' has already been declared

no, the code above is the only code I have in my js file. am running the code  in sublime text

Comment: don't declare `username` try `document.getElementById('usernameblank').value.trim`

Answer (score 0):

Because you cant reassigne Constants. If you declare a constant once you will never be able to change it again, and what you do is trying to change the value by removing the whitespace you should declare it as `var` or `let`

```
let username = document.getElementById('usernameblank');
```

or

```
var username = document.getElementById('usernameblank');
```

Comment: but am not reassigning the const. am using it. and I ve already tried with let. I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

I tried below code and its working fine. Hope it works for you !

**HTML Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Type something..." id="usernameblank" >
    <input type="button" value="Get Value" onclick=usernamevalide();>   
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript Code**

```
const username = document.getElementById('usernameblank');

function usernamevalide(){
      const usernamevalue = username.value.trim();
      alert(usernamevalue);

}
```